# Is there a way to monitor file access

Tags: monitoring, tail

I need a way to monitor the moment a file is accessed. Something similar to Tail (but for windows). The file that is being accessed is not a text file but a binary (*.wav) file. While it would help if some C# code were available, a command line app that monitors file access would be great as well.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6702/monitoring-file-access-on-windows

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope this helps:

`Get-ChildItem .\filename.wav -File | select LastAccessTime`

You might want to put that in a loop and also a condition in order to monitor file access time.

Comment: Thanks. The lastaccesstime does provide a solution. Not a perfect one (I actually neede to monitor when files are loadedf/unloaded). but its a step ion right direction. Oh.. one needs to enable a registry setting in order to monitor last access date in Win 7 and above\